# Use public key in RSA algorithm

Tags: c#, cryptography, uwp, win-universal-app, rsa

I have desktop C# code (console, wpf etc) which generate key from base64 string and encrypt by it.

```
string b64Key = "";
byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(b64Key);
int modLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(decoded.Take(4).Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
byte[] mod = decoded.Skip(4).Take(modLength).ToArray();
int expLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(decoded.Skip(modLength + 4).Take(4).Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
byte[] exponent = decoded.Skip(modLength + 8).Take(expLength).ToArray();

RSAParameters key = new RSAParameters();
key.Modulus = mod;
key.Exponent = exponent;

var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
provider.ImportParameters(key);
var encrypted = provider.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("string"), true);
```

I must reuse this part of code for UWP project.

I tried many ways but every time I catch an exception when I am trying to import public key:

```
// try to use DESKTOP key for understanding
byte[] mod = key.Modulus;
byte[] exponent = key.Exponent;
// this method concat arrays
var buf = this.Combine(mod, exponent);

// try to create key buffer from array
IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(buf);
// try to create key buffer from base64 string
keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String("base64 string");

var provider = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);
var publicKey = provider.ImportPublicKey(keyBuffer, CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Pkcs1RsaPublicKey);
// I tried all values in 'CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType' enum

var encryptData = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(publicKey, CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary("string", BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8), null);
```

How can I import key correctly for the UWP project?

Thanks!

Comment: What are  the exceptions and on which line do you get hem?

Comment: @rene it is always occurred when I invoke 'ImportPublicKey' method. There are few types of exceptions:


1. ASN1 bad tag value met. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8009310B)


2. Exception from HRESULT: 0x90090005

Answer (score 0):

At the first - I have only correct modulus and all. My base64 string is not correct public key (key in this string but there are a lot of other items). 
After that I found only one right way to generate public key from modulus and exponent -> combine them. But I was still had exception. After that I tried to generate default key and change modulus part in it -> and it worked!

```
           var provider = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaOaepSha1);
            // create custom (random) key with size '1024'
            var standardKeyPair = provider.CreateKeyPair(1024);
            // export publick key to this default key
            var standardBuffer = standardKeyPair.ExportPublicKey(CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Pkcs1RsaPublicKey);
            // copy it to bytes array
            byte[] standardKey;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(standardBuffer, out standardKey);

            // change part of the key to our modules
            // I DON'T KNOW WHY, but starndart key has 7 bytes in prefix and 5 in suffix (nail) 
            // we have 128 bytes in modulus and 140 in default key -> so we must make 140 bytes from our modulus
            Array.Copy(modulus, 0, standardKey, 7, modulus.Length);
```